# Replicating a fancy bordered text style in LaTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf, book-design, border

I am looking to replicate the following artwork with LaTeX:
[image]

A border resembling a pencil runs along the left-hand side. The pencil is divided into coloured sections corresponding to different pieces of information. Each piece of text is also given a 'reference' (subtitle) of varying lengths. The coloured rounded rectangular tab surrounding each subtitle should also vary in length to fit the entire subtitle.

How can this be achieved with tikz?

The following code by Marco Daniel can be used as a starting point and achieves a similar (but much simplified) effect where a line is drawn along only the left-hand side of a certain piece of text.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[x11names, svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{fourier-orns}
\definecolor{warningColor}{named}{Red3}
\tikzset{
  warningsymbol/.style={
      rectangle,
      draw=warningColor,
      fill=white,
      scale=1,
      overlay}
}

\mdfdefinestyle{warning}{%
 hidealllines=true,leftline=true,
 skipabove=12,skipbelow=12pt,
 innertopmargin=0.4em,%
 innerbottommargin=0.4em,%
 innerrightmargin=0.7em,%
 rightmargin=0.7em,%
 innerleftmargin=1.7em,%
 leftmargin=0.7em,%
 middlelinewidth=.2em,%
 linecolor=warningColor,%
 fontcolor=warningColor,%
 firstextra={\path let \p1=(P), \p2=(O) in ($(\x2,0)+0.5*(0,\y1)$) 
                           node[warningsymbol] {\danger};},%
 secondextra={\path let \p1=(P), \p2=(O) in ($(\x2,0)+0.5*(0,\y1)$) 
                           node[warningsymbol] {\danger};},%
 middleextra={\path let \p1=(P), \p2=(O) in ($(\x2,0)+0.5*(0,\y1)$) 
                           node[warningsymbol] {\danger};},%
 singleextra={\path let \p1=(P), \p2=(O) in ($(\x2,0)+0.5*(0,\y1)$) 
                           node[warningsymbol] {\danger};},%
}

\newmdenv[style=warning]{Warning}

\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}
\begin{Warning}
    \lipsum[1]
\end{Warning}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{Warning}
    \lipsum\lipsum[1]
\end{Warning}

\lipsum[1]


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2.71mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing,positioning,shapes.misc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily,pics/fancy box/.style={code={
 \path (0,0) coordinate (C0);
 \foreach \Item/\Text [count=\Count starting from 0] in {#1}
 {\pgfmathsetmacro{\mycolor}{{\lstColors}[\Count]}
 \node[rounded rectangle,rounded rectangle left arc=none,fill=\mycolor,anchor=north west] 
 (RR\Count) at (C\Count){\Item};
 \node[anchor=north west,below right=1ex of RR\Count.south west,draw,
 text width=5cm] (T\Count) {\Text};
 \coordinate[below left=1ex of T\Count.south west] (C\the\numexpr\Count+1\relax);
 \fill[\mycolor!50!gray] ([xshift=-1ex]C\Count) rectangle (C\the\numexpr\Count+1\relax);
 \fill[\mycolor] ([xshift=-2ex]C\Count) rectangle ([xshift=-1ex]C\the\numexpr\Count+1\relax);
 \fill[\mycolor!50!gray] ([xshift=-3ex]C\Count) rectangle ([xshift=-2ex]C\the\numexpr\Count+1\relax);
 \ifnum\Count=0
  \path[ball color=\mycolor!50] ([xshift=-3ex]C\Count) to[out=90,in=90]
  (C\Count);
 \fi
 \xdef\myCount{\Count}
 }
 \fill[brown!10,decoration={bumps,segment length=1.96ex}] ([xshift=-3ex]C\the\numexpr\myCount+1\relax) 
  -- ++ (1.5ex,-4ex) coordinate[pos=0.8] (aux1) coordinate[pos=1] (aux2) 
  -- (C\the\numexpr\myCount+1\relax) coordinate[pos=0.2] (aux3)
  -- ++ (0,0.1) decorate {-- ([xshift=-3ex,yshift=1mm]C\the\numexpr\myCount+1\relax)};
 \fill[gray] (aux1) -- (aux2) -- (aux3);
 }}]
 \edef\lstColors{"orange","green","purple","cyan"}
 \pic{fancy box={Reference/Text,Another Reference/Text,More/Body of the text,%
 Reference/Body of the text with a lot of details and the usual blablabla}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome back @marmot

Comment: This is an excellent answer! Is there a way of increasing the gap between the section header and the rounded end of the rectangle and removing the tiny vertical space between the rounded rectangle and pencil?

Comment: @wrb98 To remove the gap, set the `outer sep` to `0pt`: `\node[rounded rectangle,rounded rectangle left
 arc=none,fill=\mycolor,anchor=north west,outer sep=0pt] 
 (RR\Count) at (C\Count){\Item};` The distances are fixed by the `below` keys, try e.g. `\node[anchor=north west,below right=2ex and 1ex of RR\Count.south west,draw,
 text width=5cm] (T\Count) {\Text};
 \coordinate[below left=2ex and 1ex of T\Count.south west] (C\the\numexpr\Count+1\relax);` to double the vertical distance.